# Controlling multiple lights (stairs and basement) with motion-detector

Tags: electrical, lighting, stairs, motion-sensor

As you can see in this photo, I have an unlit stairway down to my basement. At the bottom of the stairs to the right is a door to my basement-level garage. We use these stairs frequently. I want them to be well-lit, and I want the lights to be automatic.

The garage also has a second door into the same basement hallway (at the other end, below the upper portion of the stairs).

The basement hallway was 2 office-like fluorescent lights in the hall + 1 normal light at the bottom of the stairs.

2 switches control the 1 light at the bottom of the stairs: one switch is at the top of the stairs (see blue circle), and one is at the bottom (see red circle).

There is 1 switch to control the 2 hall ceiling lights (when you get down to the bottom of the stairs, it's on the left; see green circle).

How could I accomplish something like this:

- add a new light near the top of the stairs, probably on the wall directly above the switches shown there (but closer to the ceiling)
- connect that light + the light at the bottom of the stairs + both hall lights all to the same circuit
- have 2 or more motion detectors (maybe one near the top of the stairs, one near the garage door at the bottom of the stairs, and one near the other garage door) that trigger all of the lights on[image]

P.S. Are there any wifi-connected products (such as Kasa) that help with this type of project?

Comment: what do you need WiFi for ?

Comment: Boy, I've never seen a better possible application for cove lights. A cove about 12" below the "ceiling" (i.e. sloping down each side wall), and the cove conceals LED strips aiming at the ceiling.   The ceiling would warmly glow and fill the space with light... and there would be no possible angle where anyone would see any light fixtures. So they wouldn't have a light in their face as they descend or ascend.

Comment: @Ruskes Maybe nothing. I just thought that maybe connecting multiple motion detectors to multiple circuits might be easiest wirelessly.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Thanks for your idea. I'm having trouble finding examples / visualizations of what you're talking about. https://www.google.com/search?q=cove+lights+stairs+ceiling&tbm=isch

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the existing boxes please?